# What are the licencing requirements to run Microsoft Enterprise Single Sign On service(SSO) on a seperate server?

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

Our BizTalk Production environment has a dedicated server (Windows Server 2012 R2 standard) to run the SSO services.

What are the licences we have to purchase for this SSO server? will a windows server licence alone suffice?

NOTE: BizTalk and SQL server are installed on seperate servers and we have appropriate product licences for these servers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about software licensing are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  [See this meta question for more details](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing); it does [suggest](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298715/1225845) that you could ask this question over on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: BizTalk Server has some specific licensing options so I think this question is perfectly legitimate with respect to installing BizTalk Server not necessarily buying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an additional Licence to install SSO on a computer running SQL Server. So the answer is no the Windows License alone is not sufficient, you need to have a SQL Server Licence for your SSO Server, if you have it then it's fine

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg634572.aspx

Comment: To clarify the marked Answer, you can install the Master Secret Server on any other computer to support a BizTalk Server Enterprise Edition Group.  It does not have to be the SQL Server.  However, the MSS should be clustered with the SSO database since the MSS is dependent on it.  So, you should not have a dedicated SSO server to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Johns-305. In our scenario we are planning to use MSS+ SSO service on a seperate server for high availability.